# Express: server unable to handle refresh when using URL param

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When using URL param, e.g. `books/1`, for some reason the express app is unable to find and serve `Index.js`.

I am using absolute path, but even still my express app is unable to find `Index.js` when refreshed at a url using params.

[image: unable to find Index.js]

As you can see in the screenshot instead of serving `Index.js` it is unable to find it and serves html file instead as the `Index.js`.

I am doing the [catch-all solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually), which works great until refreshed at a url param:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,  '..', 'build')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

I've even tried to set up a specific route for `/Index.js`, but no luck.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,  '..', 'build')));
app.get('/Index.js', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'Index.js'))
});
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

I've also tried using [serve-static](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html) instead of `express.static` but didn't help.

I've duplicated the issue in this [repo](https://github.com/schinns/refresh-issue-duplicate) if anyone is interested in taking a look.

The front-end of this project is in [reason-react](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/).

Comment: remove `./` from the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag for `Index.js`

Answer (score 0):

This may be simplistic, but have you tried: `res.sendFile('../public/index.js', {root: __dirname});`

Comment: I just tried that  and I got a `403 (Forbidden)` when refreshing.

Comment: Is your file path correct? `../public/index.js`, your file path could be `../src/index.js` for example.

Comment: yes, the path is correct. its actually `../build/Index.js`. I am certain it is correct because the express serves the files successfully *__except__* when the page refreshes on a param url. thats when it seems the path is lost somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Serving Index.js on the mountpath "book/Index.js" fixed the issue.

Like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,  '..', 'build')));
app.get('/book/Index.js', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'Index.js'));
});
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```